# QT Unit Testing moc "unresolved external symbol" for QMetaObject

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

I'm trying to add unit tests to a project of mine for the first time.

I can run mock tests alright (without using my project's classes) and run the application alright. But if I instantiate objects from the project I get an unresolved external symbol of the QMetaObject. If I recall correctly, this means the moc of the object isn't being included on the project.

How do I fix this? I have the same issue using googletests. The guide also doesn't help on this. I've tried installing the qt unit testing plugin, same result.

I've uploaded a mock project that follows the same structure that I'm using in the aforementioned project, fetch it here: https://github.com/quimnuss/QtUnitTestingTest

I'm using a static build of qt on windows, but I guess that's irrellevant. Using QtCreator as IDE and NMAke build.

I've also tried add the HelloWorld.lib, but taking a look at the Makefile.release it isn't used.

Somebody has an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the unit testing .pro:

```
QT       += widgets network testlib

TARGET = tst_someunittesttest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../HelloWorld

include($$PWD/../HelloWorld/helloworldCommon.pri)

LIBS += -L"$$OUT_PWD/../HelloWorld/release"
LIBS += -lHelloWorld

message("Searching libs here $$LIBS")

SOURCES += tst_someunittesttest.cpp
DEFINES += SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD/\\\"
```

The first error's complete message:

```
tst_someunittesttest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl HelloWorld::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@HelloWorld@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
```

Comment: I have reviewed your project, I understand that the project you want to test is HelloWorld, within that project there are 2 classes: HelloWorld and MainWindow. I do not understand why you want to link a library you have not created. Aside the HelloWorld class has never been used. Exactly what do you want to test (the HelloWorld class or the MainWindow class)?

Comment: On that mock example, the `HelloWorld`. I'm testing the function `returnsTrue` that it returns `true` indeed. Buildling that project creates the HelloWorld.lib, althought I'm not sure if that's needed for the unit testing since the sources are there anyway.

Comment: If it is necessary to build the library since in your .pro is written LIBS + = -lHelloWorld. I have built the testing in a moment I will upload the code.

Comment: In the link is the solution: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/QtUnitTestingTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the following flags:

```
LIBS += -L"$$OUT_PWD/../HelloWorld/release"
LIBS += -lHelloWorld
```

You must have the compiled dynamic or static library. Therefore you must create a project generating a library. In the next part I show you how to create a dynamic library.

**HelloWorldLib.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-01-06T12:37:49
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       -= gui

TARGET = HelloWorldLib
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += HELLOWORLDLIB_LIBRARY

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include

SOURCES += src/helloworldlib.cpp

HEADERS += include/helloworldlib.h\
        include/helloworldlib_global.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}

DESTDIR = $$PWD/lib
```

**include/helloworldlib.h**

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLDLIB_H
#define HELLOWORLDLIB_H

#include "helloworldlib_global.h"

#include <QDebug>

class HELLOWORLDLIBSHARED_EXPORT HelloWorldLib: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    HelloWorldLib(){

    }
    static bool returnTrue()
    {
        return true;
    }

public slots:
    void someSlot()
    {
        qDebug() << "test";
    }
};

#endif // HELLOWORLDLIB_H
```

**include/helloworldlib_global.h**

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLDLIB_GLOBAL_H
#define HELLOWORLDLIB_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(HELLOWORLDLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define HELLOWORLDLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define HELLOWORLDLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // HELLOWORLDLIB_GLOBAL_H
```

**src/helloworldlib.cpp**

```
#include "helloworldlib.h"
```

Here I show the test project.

**HelloWorldTest.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-01-06T12:42:42
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT += testlib
QT -= gui

# greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = tst_helloworldtesttest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += tst_helloworldtesttest.cpp
DEFINES += SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD/\\\"

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../HelloWorldLib/lib/release/ -lHelloWorldLib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../HelloWorldLib/lib/debug/ -lHelloWorldLib
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../HelloWorldLib/lib/ -lHelloWorldLib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../HelloWorldLib/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../HelloWorldLib/include
```

**tst_helloworldtesttest.cpp**

```
#include <QString>
#include <QtTest>

#include <helloworldlib.h>

#include <QDebug>

class HelloWorldTestTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    HelloWorldTestTest();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void testCase1_data();
    void testCase1();
};

HelloWorldTestTest::HelloWorldTestTest()
{
}

void HelloWorldTestTest::testCase1_data()
{
    QTest::addColumn<QString>("data");
    QTest::newRow("0") << QString();
}

void HelloWorldTestTest::testCase1()
{
    QFETCH(QString, data);
    QVERIFY2(true, "Failure");

    HelloWorldLib hw;
    QVERIFY(hw.returnTrue());

}

QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN(HelloWorldTestTest)

#include "tst_helloworldtesttest.moc"
```

Output:

```
********* Start testing of HelloWorldTestTest *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.7.1, Qt 5.7.1 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 6.2.1 20160830)
PASS   : HelloWorldTestTest::initTestCase()
PASS   : HelloWorldTestTest::testCase1(0)
PASS   : HelloWorldTestTest::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 3 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted, 0ms
********* Finished testing of HelloWorldTestTest *********
```

In the following link is the complete project: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/QtUnitTestingTest

Comment: Thanks for the complete solution! More than I expected. I have an undefined symbol as well, as if it were ignoring the lib. Output error: https://gist.github.com/quimnuss/ce638019cfd5abb3572e761761bdb47f
I had to add a win switch so the lib landed at lib/release (see end of gist) otherwise it wouldn't even find it. Also, I get a warning `helloworldlib.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library` when I build only the library.

Comment: @quimnuss update my solution. Change dynamic library to static library: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/QtUnitTestingTest

Comment: Excellent! this works. I'll study it on monday and adapt it to my project. Excellent answer!